Any way to create a barrier object if number of threads are unknown until runtime?
The few examples I've seen for std:barrier statically set the expected count.
std::barrier my_barrier(5);

The code I'm writing determines the number of threads to launch based on some factors at runtime. I'm struggling to come up with a clever way to construct the barrier at runtime after the number of threads to be launched is determined. Ideas appreciated.

Construct the barrier after the number of threads is known. The parameter expected doesn't have to be a literal, no?

Do std::barrier my_barrier(my_calculated_value);?

The other part of this is that in the examples I see this set up as a global. If it's calculated it needs to be at a non-global scope. I guess maybe I missing something. I don't see how to pass it as a local into the threads. Thanks for -1 LOL.

There really aren't many examples, I did spend time looking before I posted.

Examples may create a std::barrier at "global scope", but that doesn't mean you should.  Most cases in which objects are created as globals are poor practice anyway - there is nothing special about std::barrier that requires it to be at global scope.

Based on your comment:

If it's calculated it needs to be at a non-global scope. I don't see how to pass it as a local into the threads.

At some point the barrier has to be somewhat 'global'. Sure it doesn't make sense to put the barrier globally at e.g. file scope (deleted copy ctor and assignment operator) but it does make sense to put the barrier into the scope where the (dynamic amount of) workers will be invoked. Then the barrier has to be made local to the thread function. There are multiple ways to do that, it all depends whether you're using a lambda, function object or a function. So either via capture (lambda), as a class member (function object) or as argument (all).
e.g.
void invoke(int num_threads)
{
    //completition function, will be invoked after all threads arrived at the barrier
    auto on_completion = []() noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "done\n";
    };

    //construct barrier
    std::barrier sync_point(num_threads, on_completion);

    //work function (could be also a function object or a function, here we use a lambda)
    auto work = [&sync_point /*either capture*/](/*or as argument*/)
    {
        //do something, then
        //wait for all threads to arrive
        sync_point.arrive_and_wait();
    };

    //construct workers
    std::vector<std::jthread> threads;    //dynamic array of threads
    threads.reserve(num_threads);         //alloc space
    for (int n=0; n < num_threads; ++n) { //for each thread in list
        //invoke the work function
        threads.emplace_back(work /*, pass the function arguments here*/);
    }
}

then
int main()
{
    int n = 4;
    invoke(n);
}


Thanks, your explanation and example clarified things for me, and I now have my code working correctly.  I'm updating my code from pthreads to jthreads and adding the barrier function, so again really helpful example.  I mistakenly though that the invoke() function would exit after the threads were launched, and the barrier would be destroyed. But In the code I wrote based on your example I see that is not the case.  Best, Gene

@geenweb std::jthread::~jthread: If *this has an associated thread (joinable() == true), calls request_stop() and then join(). Thus, invoke will not return until all threads have finished execution.
